# Why isnt my phone vibrating when i press the button?

Tags: java, android

Hi im trying to make it that when a user clicks on on a button the phone vibrates. Heres manifest.xml and AndroidVibrator.java so whats wrong? how can i fix it? thanks!

heres the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity

            android:name=".AndroidActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity android:name=".activity2"
                   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                   android:label="@string/app_name"  >


         </activity>

         <activity android:name=".activity3"
                   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                   android:label="@string/app_name" >

         </activity>

         <activity android:name=".next" >

         </activity>






    </application>




</manifest>
```

Heres AndroidActivity:

```
package android.app;
import android.app.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Vibrator;

public class AndroidVibrator extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private View myView;
    private Vibrator myVib;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myVib = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        //myView can be any type of view, button, etc.
        myView = (View) this.findViewById(R.id.sound);
        myView.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        myVib.vibrate(50);
        //add whatever you want after this
    }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Check phone settings, whether Vibration is disabled.

Comment: @Manik I just started using vibes in my app, and tested turning off vibes on my phone so the back and home buttons don't vibe, but my app still does... do i need to check if the user's phone currently has vibes disabled and not do the vibe?

Comment: @towpse which event of your app vibes?
Keyboard Press or normal touch on views?

Comment: @Manik yeah after disabling sound -> vibe on touch, keyboard press still vibes in my app, as do events where i specifically ask for a vibe to happen using vibrator.vibrate(10), such as on some click/touch events i set up since they don't seem to vibe by default.

Comment: @towpse To disable vibes on keyboard press, 
Phone Settings -> Language & input -> Keyboard setting -> uncheck the "Sound on Keypress". In Android we have two haptic effects, one for keyboard & another for home/back key press!

Comment: @Manik, right for sure. but after i disable both sound/vibe on keypress and vibe on touch, even tho back/home and keyboard no longer have vibes, the vibrator.vibrate method i use in my app to provide haptic feedback still vibrates. do i need to have my app itself check to see if the user has vibration enabled or disabled before invoking vibrator.vibrate?

Comment: @towpse are you using native keyboard or some 3rd party keyboard?

Comment: @Manik it's the native one as far as i know. just the default one that pops up when you tap on an edit text.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you call

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

In your manifest

EDIT:

Try putting your permission at the end of the manifest, or after version code.

Answer (score 1):

I've responded to your previous post about the same matter

this time you place the permissions over uses sdk...

check my other answer.

Also check the ouput of LogCat. Does your application force closes?

Answer (score 0):

may be 50 ms is too short to feel vibrate
try more than 50ms